# Mass update customer attribute programatically in a single query

Tags: magento2, customer, massaction

I've created a custom customer attribute via install script.

Now I would like to bulk update this attribute for batches of customers programmatically. Preferably in a single query (using foreach would be inefficient).

If I understand this correctly in case of products there's `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductAction`, but there is no customer equivalent for this.